# Application-defined or object-defined error with formula VBA

Tags: vba, excel, formula, vlookup

I'm new to VBA and encounter the

> application-defined or object-defined error

while doing it.

```
Set twb = ThisWorkbook
Set extwbk = Workbooks.Open("abc.xlsx")
Set x = extwbk.Worksheets("FILTERED").Range("$A:$A")

With twb.Sheets("FILTERED")

    For rw = 9 To .Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        .Cells(rw, 34).Formula = "=IF(ISERROR(VLOOKUP(.Cells(rw, 1).Value2, x, 1, False))=TRUE,""New"",""Old"")"
    Next rw

End With
```

This can be done manually but I'm asked to do it by programming. It is simply apply the formula from AH9 to the end of the data. May I know is there any coding error in the for loop?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dont put VBA variables inside your string formula. *Resolve them* in VBA and inject the result into the formula:

```
 .Formula = "=IF(ISERROR(VLOOKUP(" & .Cells(rw, 1).Value2 & "," & _
   x.Address(External:=True) & ", 1, False))=TRUE,""New"",""Old"")"
```

p.s. dont use `=TRUE` to check for a boolean, things like `If ISERROR(Something) = TRUE` don't make sense. Just `If ISERROR(Something)`.

```
.Formula = "=IF(ISERROR(VLOOKUP(" & .Cells(rw, 1).Value2 & "," & _
  x.Address(External:=True) & ", 1, False)),""New"",""Old"")"
```

---

If you want the formula to be dynamic and recalculate accordingly when the cell at `(rw, 1)` changes in the future, use `.Address` instead of `.Value2`:

```
'                                                vvvvvvvv
.Formula = "=IF(ISERROR(VLOOKUP(" & .Cells(rw, 1).Address & "," & _
  x.Address(External:=True) & ", 1, False)),""New"",""Old"")"
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. It works successfully. One more question : As this code results in looking up the exact value in A9. I don't know why the result would be different by changing the exact value to the cell A9.

Comment: @AngYiwei if you want the formula to be dynamic and recalculate when `A9` changes, replace `.Cells(rw, 1).Value2` with `.Cells(rw, 1).Address`. Is that what you want? (See added last part of the answer)

Comment: Thanks for answering. I did that by replacing it to " & "$A" & rw & " and both work as well. However what I concern is that the same cells (with formula), one with exact value and one with its position which both give two different results after vlookup.

Comment: @AngYiwei That's weird. What kind of data is it in that cell? (`A9`)

Comment: There is a formula in A9 which is based on B9,E9 and AC9. I wonder if it is caused by the formula.
    [=IF(E9="A",IF(LEFT(AC9,2)="B",LEFT(AC9,12),B9),B9)].